# Padding to get specific number of digits in a number

Tags: java, grails, groovy

```
String val = "98"
```

I need to get the output  as `0000098` (7 digits).

I need left padding of zeros to the string or integer value...

The number stored in val is dynamic and may contain any number of digits, but the output should always be 7 digits.

Answer (score 26):

In groovy, you can pad Strings like so:

```
val.padLeft( 7, '0' )
```

That will pad the left of the string with zeros until it is 7 chars in length

Answer (score 15):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
public class A {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%07d", 98)); // -> 0000098
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html which gives functions like `leftpad`, `rightpad` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can format your String value using NumberFormat in this way:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0000000");
```

It means that your String will be completed with 0s as you want.

And then, to get your String formatted you can do:

```
String formatRes = formatter.format(new Double(val));
```

because the "format" method needs a double as argument.